# Very simple self-join, yet indeces ignored?

Tags: mysql, indexing, self-join

Got a noob question. Say I create the following table:

### temp1

up, varchar(15)

dn, varchar(15)

and I add a couple of indeces:

```
create table temp1 (up varchar(15), dn varchar(15), index id1(up), index id2(dn))
```

After I populate the table with some random data, I do the following explain select

```
explain select * from temp1 as t1, temp1 as t2 where t1.up = t2.up
```

and get

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL  | id1           | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ALL  | id1           | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Why isn't the optimizer using the keys?! I must be missing something very simple . . .

(I'm asking this question because a similar query with the tables I'm actually using (700K rows) is running awfully slow, and I'm guessing it has to do with indeces).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you select all the rows from temp t1 (and almost all from t2) - mysql decides to use fullscan, due to it is more suitable in such case.

Comment: Mhmm, interesting. So if the table temp1 was much larger, the optimizer would use the index, but only on the "2nd" table?

Comment: @Misha: It is worth to use indexes when the result set (of select, join, nested select, etc) is less than approximately 30% of total rows (the number is **very approximate** and the real amount is calculated based on lot of criterias).

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but this would return ALL values of your table temp1. It would not help you to use any indexes, because you are not looking for a subset of anything.

Comment: The condition that pairs t2 rows to each t1 row based on the 'up' value would use an index.They simply doesn't have enough random data in the table for the index to be any faster than using the data itself.